# How to find Perimeter and Area?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have this question:
A rancher has 480 feet of fencing with which to enclose two adjacent rectangular corrals. What dimensions should be used so that the enclosed area will be a maximum?
x=....ft
y=....ft

Below is my work:

1. P=4x+2y
2. A=2xy

480=4x+2y

240-2x=y

A=2x(240-2x)

480x-4x^2

I cannot figure out what do I have to do next???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @Sara, I think $x,y$ are the length & breadth. But, could you draw the picture ?

Comment: We could always make a big corral and a micro-corral stuck to the side of the big one, for the use of a micro-horse. It would have been nice if the problem had specified the meaning of adjacent, presumably that they share a *full* side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there are two **adjacent** rectangular corrals, we need for perimeter to be such that $$P = 3x+2y = 480\iff 2y = 480 - 3x \iff y = 240 - \frac 32 x$$

Where $3x$ counts the three sides, one of which is shared by each rectangle.

Then Area is $x y$...$y$ being the width across the large rectangle,  and $x$ being the length of the large rectangle containing the adjacent rectangles.

$$A = xy = x\left(240 - \frac 32 x\right) = 240 x - \frac 32 x^2$$

Now find $A'(x)$ and set that equal to $0$ and solve for maximum $x$.

$$A'(x) = 240 - 3x = 0 \iff 3x = 240 \iff x = 80\;\text{feet}$$

$$y = 240 - \frac 32 x = 240 - 120 = 120\;\text{feet}$$

So the large rectangle will be 120 feet across top and bottom, and 80 feet along each side: Two outer sides, one inner (middle/dividing) side.

Comment: Well that's what I gat x=80, and y=120 and it was wrong?

Comment: Well, it's correct, perhaps a typo in the solutions?

Comment: Each of the two adjacent corrals will then by $x \times y/2:$ 80 feet long, 60 feet wide.

Comment: I came to this answer: x=60, y=240/3. I'm not sure if I'm correct?

Comment: Yes, did you see my comment: we could have 80 by 60 rectangles, but there'd be two of them: two 60 feet by 80 feet, but they'd be side by side, sharing an 80 foot fence. So we still get the big rectangle 120 feet by 80 feet. It **depends on what you call x, y**: in essence, we'd have three sides of fencing each 80 feet long, and 4 sides of fencing, each 60 feet. Two of each of the 60 ft fencing will be joined to make a long two 120 ft long fences. Just as long as you make clear what $x$ and $y$ each mean, you're fine with the answer.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Thanks! Here what I did: 4x+3y=480 is the perimeter: A=2xy=2x(480-4x/3)=8/3(120x-x^2). dA/dx=8/3(120-2x)=0 when x=60. d^2A/dx^2=-16/3<0 when x=60. A is maximum when x=60 ft and y=240/3.

Comment: You're welcome, Sara!!